# Sending only data trough firebase services

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications, firebase-console

Is it possible to send a notification trough firebase services dashboard with data without notification object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, a notification sent from the firebase console will always have the `"notification"` field.

Comment: For that you will have to use the REST API.